# How to select elements inside a DIV?

Tags: css-selectors

How can I address all inner elements of a div, if I don't know what they are?

```
<div class="outer">
   <p> 
   <a href="the_room.html"> Hi, Mark! </a> 
   </p>
   <div class="inner"></div>
<div>
```

Say, in this case I want to get everything in the outer div and get maybe an HTMLcollection or an array of a, p, div.inner. Though I'm not supposed to know they are a, p and div.

Comment: hi, for the direct children you can use the child selector with a wildcard `.outer > *`, for all descendants you could use `.outer *`

Answer (score 1):

`*` is the "select-all" (wildcard) selector

`.outer *`